Possible explanations for an operation hanging indefinitely with a redundant constraint?
During a GHC upgrade we noticed one particular test case seemed to just hang forever (at runtime, not compile time). In searching for a looping bottom value lurking somewhere I found a startling fact, while simplifying an instance declaration:
This exhibited the hanging:
-- Note now-redundant constraint
instance ( Eq (Bar b a)) => Eq (Foo b a) where
  _ == _ = False

This did not (the operation finished promptly):
-- constraint removed
instance Eq (Foo b a) where
  _ == _ = False

We use UndecidableInstances heavily and so this question caught my eye, but I don't see how the variations above could trigger/resolve an infinite loop like the one discussed there.
My question is how the observed behavior could possibly occur, and an answer would hopefully offer a simple reproducer that builds on the snippet here.
FWIW the change in behavior happens between 9.6.6 and 9.8.2

What's the definition of Foo, Bar, Bar's Eq instance, and the hanging operation? Have you determined whether it's a single call to == that's looping, or an operation that uses == multiple times and can't finish? My first wild guess is that a bogus == where x /= x could easily break assumptions needed for some algorithm, and maybe the presence of the constraint (runtime dictionary argument) prevents the compiler from optimising something that short-circuited the loop (and the optimisation behaviour differs between versions)? But you really haven't given a lot of context here.

"But you really haven't given a lot of context here." Indeed. In particular, are all the instances defined in the same module? All imported to the module where the Eq (Foo b a) instances is declared? Scattered all over the place ...? In face of UndecidableInstances and scattered-asunder instance decls, GHC has to defer checking 'til it can see all the instances.

While it probably boils down to that instance, it might be because the Foo and Bar are related in one way or another besides the instance. So probably it requires a bit more context to make this a MWE.

The onus is usually on the asker to provide an MWE for their problem.

@Ben If it's unclear _ == _ = False is the actual instance body I'm dealing with in my repro case. I'm repro-ing without optimizations but that's an interesting idea. If anyone wants to repro my actual issue they are welcome to try here, but I think my question in the penultimate paragraph is reasonable and clear; a self-contained example that contains those exact instance bodies and demonstrates a loop with one and not the other would suffice.

@jberryman I concur with Ben: the question is not reasonable and clear. If I copy and paste your code into a text editor, I get scope errors, not a runtime loop. Defining trivial data types and adding a Language UndecidableInstances pragma was not enough, either. Not to mention you haven't said what invocation causes the loop! This is missing too many details to reproduce locally.

@jberryman It's clear what you want, it's just a very open ended and non-trivial thing to do. Cutting down what you've got to a smaller reproduction sounds like a much more plausible path to characterising the issue then speculatively building out from here. If you're having specific problems when trying to cut it down you could probably get some on-topic questions out of that (although it sounds from your link that your case is very non-minimal at the moment if you have to have a postgresql database running, so you'd have to be able to focus the Q's more narrowly).

@jberryman I'd at least try putting in some trace prints and try to figure out a tighter bound on what is being called before it hangs.

Well, I hoped the question would be trivial for someone with the right expertise: "sure here's a 8 line example of a runtime loop that I can toggle off by removing a redundant constraint". Or "this is only explainable as a bottom dictionary, which should be impossible even under UndecidableInstances". Appreciate the input though
